# Amazon Web Services, Read store DynamoDB Json data in Android program

Tags: java, android, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I store Json Data into a DynamoDB table, the data looks like this:

```
"payload": {
"M": {
  "state": {
    "M": {
      "reported": {
        "M": {
          "alive": {
            "BOOL": true
          },
          "reg": {
            "N": "0"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "N": "1520357203.4857106"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to retrieve this data to an android program, using the scan command to read all the data in the table:

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
      List<PcObject2DO> result = dynamoDBMapper.scan(PcObject2DO.class, scanExpression);
```

Where

```
PcObject2DO
```

is the class with the accesors methods that Amazon provide for the DynamoDB table, all fields in the table are strings, simply.
I receive this error in the scan command:

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: Expected S in value {M:......
```

and mentioned the use of custom marshaler, the problem is retrieve the data of the field "payload" that is in DynamoDB Json format. The documentation about read Json and the use of marshalers are vague and not cover all needs.
After Investigate in forums and get sample code, I tested using marshalers of many types, create a class for the payload, and also change the type of the table accesors, but the problem is still there, the data of the payload field cannot be retrieved.

I Include the payload class, the custom marshaller, and the changes made in the table accesors, the changes are commented. Sorry, Im new in android and AWS, I understand the concept of the marshaler and the seriealized data, but I really dont know how do this or if is possible.

PcObject2DO.java

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-thing")

public class PcObject2DO {
    private String _reg;
    private String _timestamp;
    private String _payload;

    //private Map<String, Payload> _payload;

    //private static final JsonMarshaller<Payload>PAYLOAD_JSON_MARSHALLER    = new JsonMarshaller<Payload>();

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "reg")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "reg")
    public String getReg() {
        return _reg;
    }

    public void setReg(final String _reg) {
        this._reg = _reg;
    }
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "timestamp")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "timestamp")
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return _timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(final String _timestamp) {
        this._timestamp = _timestamp;
    }
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "payload")
    public String getPayload() {
        return _payload;
   }
    public void setPayload(final String  _payload) {
        this._payload = _payload;
    }
    /*public Set<String> getPayload() {
        if(_payload !=null){
            Set<String> jsonSet = new HashSet<String>(_payload.size());
            for(Payload data : _payload){
                String json = PAYLOAD_JSON_MARSHALLER.marshall(data);
                jsonSet.add(json);
            }
            return jsonSet;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void setPayload(Set<String> jsonSet) {
        if(jsonSet != null){
            _payload = new HashSet<Payload>(jsonSet.size());
            for(String json : jsonSet){
                Payload data =    PAYLOAD_JSON_MARSHALLER.unmarshall(Payload.class, json);
                _payload.add(data);
            }
        }
    }*/
    //-----
}
```

Payload.Java

```
public class Payload {
    private Boolean alive;
    private int reg;
    private String timestamp;

    public Boolean getAlive() {return alive;}
    public void setAlive(Boolean alive) {this.alive = alive;}

    public int getReg() {return  reg;}
    public void setReg(int reg){this.reg = reg;}

    public String getTimestamp() {return  timestamp;}
    public void  setTimestamp(String timestamp) {this.timestamp = timestamp;}
}
```

PayloadMarshaller.java

```
public class PayloadMarshaller implements    DynamoDBMarshaller<List<Payload>> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

    @Override
    public String marshall(List<Payload> obj ) {
        try {
            return writer.writeValueAsString(obj);
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
     }

    @Override
    public List<Payload> unmarshall (Class<List<Payload>> clazz, String json){
        final CollectionType type =    mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Payload.class);
        try{
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you paste the whole error it looks like you have not paste the full error description in here  "Expected S in value {M:......"   this is incomplete

Comment: Yes, the complete error is: 
 com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: Expected S in value {M: {state={M: {reported={M: {timestamp={N: 1520357233.4884267,}, reg={N: 1,}, alive={BOOL: true}},}},}},} when invoking public void com.amazonaws.models.nosql.PcObject2DO.setPayload(java.lang.String)

Comment: The issue because of the structure, you need to have attributes like _reg at root level or marshall from inside map rather than using it at object level.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, how unmarshal correctly the DynamoDB data, many marshallers like DynamoDBMarshaller, or jackson, but the documentation not mention how to do this for the class DynamodDBMapper

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a boolean instead of a String

```
 "alive": {
        "BOOL": true
      },
```

Comment: I try to read a complex data that includes a Map type, a Bool, and a number, the data is serialized. The accesor data type is a String, the data need be deserialized first to store after in the string variable. This is the problem, I don't know how deserialize.

Comment: I never used marshaller before let me check my previous works how I did all the stuff

Comment: which aws sdk are you using because I never used marshmaller for my android projects

Comment: AWS SDK Mobile client 2.6, AWS SDK Dbd Mapper 2.6

Comment: could you post an example of your data , you said you data looks like this and it looks weird  with the java classes you put there , if you can do that I might help you better and did you know about DynamoDB_DocumentAPI for android ?

Comment: The data looks like this: { "state" : { "M" : { "reported" : { "M" : { "alive" : { "BOOL" : true }, "reg" : { "N" : "1" }, "timestamp" : { "N" : "1520357233.4884267" } } } } } } I wanted read that and put it all in a string variable, that is all. Supposedly It cannot be read because is not a string, is a serialized json. The AWS Documentation is really, rally bad, barey explain certain things, is almost useless.